# Issue in renaming Json parsed field in Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am parsing json log file in Logstash. There is a field named @person.name. I tried to rename this field name before sending it to elasticsearch. I also tried to remove the field but I couldn't remove or delete that field because of that my data not getting indexed in Elasticsearch.

**Error recorded in elasticsearch**

```
MapperParsingException[Field name [@person.name] cannot contain '.']
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseProperties(ObjectMapper.java:276)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseObjectOrDocumentTypeProperties(ObjectMapper.java:221)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parse(ObjectMapper.java:196)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseProperties(ObjectMapper.java:308)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseObjectOrDocumentTypeProperties(ObjectMapper.java:221)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.RootObjectMapper$TypeParser.parse(RootObjectMapper.java:138)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:119)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:100)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:435)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.applyRequest(MetaDataMappingService.java:257)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataMappingService$PutMappingExecutor.execute(MetaDataMappingService.java:230)    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService.runTasksForExecutor(InternalClusterService.java:458)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:762)
```

**My Logstash config**

```
input {
       beats {
            port => 11153
        }
    }
    filter 
    {
        if [type] == "person_get" {
        ##Parsing JSON input to JSON Filter..
            json {          
                source => "message"
            }
            mutate{
            rename => { "@person.name" => "@person-name" }
            remove_field => [ "@person.name"]
            }

            fingerprint {
                                   source => ["ResponseTimestamp"]
                                   target => "fingerprint"
                                   key => "78787878"
                                   method => "SHA1"
                                   concatenate_sources => true
                    }

    }
    }

    output{
    if [type] == "person_get" { 
        elasticsearch {       
              index => "logstash-person_v1"
              hosts => ["xxx.xxx.xx:9200"]
              document_id => "%{fingerprint}" # !!! prevent duplication       
            }
                stdout {
                    codec => rubydebug
                }
                }         }
```

Comment: What if you run it without remove_field in your mutate? I mean your mutate renaming should work fine? Are you getting any errors when you're just having the renaming in your mutate?

Comment: I am not getting any error but the field name not getting renamed. I don't know what is happening.

Comment: I got the same problem with logstash 2.3.4

Comment: @ShawnSim My issue got resolved. If you send your config and input I will help you out.